# Error Including *.so library in Android Studio NDK Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build, android-ndk-r5

I Pasted `.so` file into my new project folder

```
jniLibs->arm64-v8a  
jniLibs->armeabi-v7a
```

Inside MainActivity.java file I declared

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("filename");
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        try {
           textView.setText(METHODNAME("string")+"");
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.i("error", e.message());
        }
    }

public static native int[] METHODNAME(String strng);
```

When I run the app it shows below error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int[] com.android.myapp.MainActivity.METHODNAME(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: You need to initialize METHODNAME. Currently it is undefined.

Comment: in the end i initialized as `public static native int[] METHODNAME(String strng);`

Comment: What you have is a declaration? You need to assign a value such as space or string.

Comment: Oh just noticed that you have an `int[]`. What is the purpose for the `int[]`

Comment: `Is it saying that it is unable to find METHODNAME() inside .so file?`  Im trying to call the method which is inside .so file and im printing it inside textview. Im new to this and i cant find any proper tuts too.

Comment: So you want to display a value inside the text view correct,

Comment: yes! which is the return value from METHODNAME() inside .so file

Comment: How about in your onCreate method initialize `String hello;` and then do something like ` hello="This is my first project";` to test out your code.

Comment: i think we are not on the same page. It is NDK project which i need to execute c code inside java(onCreate) using JNI. For this to work i am doing any thing wrong from my side?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I suggest that you update the body of question describe the problem. SO has a lot of experts that can help you. Good Luck.

Comment: What does the C++ function corresponding to `METHODNAME` look like? You will need something like `extern "C" JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_android_myapp_MainActivity_METHODNAME(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {}` in your C++ source that generates the .so library.